# Cannot erase item by index from C++ vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to learn vectors in **C++**, so I write a very basic code. Basically, I have a vector which holds pointer to person structure. Which is like this:

```
typedef struct _person
{
    unsigned long id;
    char* name;
    unsigned long age;
}person;
```

Then, I've a vector which is defined like this:

```
vector<person*> MyPersons;
```

Then, for testing I've created some person structure and push them to vector via `push_back` function. Now, for example I want to remove first person that has age 25 from my vector. So, what I do is search in vector and get index of that person, then erase that index from vector.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < MyPersons.size(); i++)
{
    pperson = MyPersons.at(i);
    if(pperson->age == 25)
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

MyPersons.erase(MyPersons.begin() + index )
```

Now, it should be remove that item from list, right? But, instead, it gives me error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Expression: vector erase iterator outside range

But this is impossible. I've debug my code with Visual Studio, and I see that index value is valid. MyPersons size is 5 and index is 2.

Any help very appreciated.
Sincerely

Comment: "MyPersons size is 5 and index is 2." if this is true, the error shouldn't occur. Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can debug the code and check what is wrong?

Comment: `char* name;` for your own sanity I strongly suggest `std::string` there

Comment: Aside: So what is index initialised to?  What happens if you don't find someone with age 25?

Comment: @Caleth Ok then.My fault.

Comment: OT: You may want to take a look at std::find (the version that takes a callable as last parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is likely that `index` is initialised to a value not in the range of `MyPersons`, so if the value isn't found then you get the error.

You should use standard algorithms for these type of task, to delete the first `person*` with age 25 you could use:

```
auto itr = std::find_if(MyPersons.cbegin(), MyPersons.cend(),
                       [] (person* pperson) { return pperson->age == 25; });
if (itr != MyPersons.cend()) MyPersons.erase(itr);
```

To delete **all** `person*`s with age 25 you could use:

```
MyPersons.erase(std::remove_if(MyPersons.begin(), MyPersons.end(),
                [] (person* pperson) { return pperson->age == 25; }),
                MyPersons.end());
```

Using standard algorithms is preferable than using hand-rolled loops. The intention is clearer, the resulting code is often less verbose, and most importantantly, standard algorithms more likely to be correct.

Also, you're probably going about things the wrong way storing pointers to your data in the `std::vector`.

Comment: Your code example introduce UB by not checking the iterator for being MyPersons.cend(): _"The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for pos."_ [std::vector::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)

Comment: The single iterator `erase` doesn't accept end iterators

Comment: Your code stills gives me same error. I'm %100 sure that index is not overflow my vector size. By the way, what do you mean by "Also, you're probably going about things the wrong way storing pointers to your data in the std::vector."  @Daniel?

Comment: @StevenK. Can you update your question with an MVE? If my code is also failing, then you probably have a bug elsewhere and you're seeing undefined behaviour.

Comment: @StevenK. My comment refers to the fact that it's generally bad practise in C++ to manually manage memory. Just use `std::vector<person>`. There is almost never a good reason to store non-`const` raw pointers in a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `typedef struct _person` preamble, that's a C-ism.

```
struct person
{
    unsigned long id;
    std::string name;
    unsigned long age;
}
```

You also don't need to `new` objects, they can be values

```
std::vector<person> people;
```

To remove the first person aged 25:

```
auto it = std::find_if(people.begin(), people.end(), [](person & p) { return p.age = 25; });
if (it != people.end()) people.erase(it);
```

To remove all people aged 25:

```
auto it = std::remove_if(people.begin(), people.end(), [](person & p) { return p.age = 25; });
people.erase(it, people.end());
```

Comment: The fact that `std::remove_if' is "just" sorting into keepable and removable values and returning the position of the first removable value is something that might also be interesting to know for OP.